# Wierd Glitchy Render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

my rig wont render properly but when I view it in texture or material I can see the skin just fine. Can someone help me?

[image: Here is the rendered view]

[image: Here is the texture]

Comment: Explain your problem in detail. Post screenshots or provide blend file

Comment: Check if you have multiple uv maps, and check which one is being used for rendering purposes. It looks like you have one selected for the viewport, but a second one selected for rendering (the camera icon)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you textured your model using the Textured Mode. The problem is that those settings don't transfer back to your material settings. For example if you have the face and the clothes on different textures Textured mode will allow you to unwrap some faces on one texture and others on the other one but the Material will ignore that.
Make sure to work in the Material Mode and set your material to Shadeless so you can see the texture better.